# SwingUtilities.convertPoint() returns negative values

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, swingutilities

I am facing this issue in another project which has complicated JPanels structure and much code.

In there I have a following snippet

```
Point point = label.getLocation();
Point point2 = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(label.getParent(), point, panel);
```

in where label and panel are selected dynamically and JLabel is supposed to be grand-grand-...-child of JPanel.

**So why question is in what case `SwingUtilities.convertPoint()` can return negative values if source and destination have child-parent relation? Is this possible at all?**

This code demonstrated negative coordinates issue, but there panel22 is not parent of label.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class NegativeLocation {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NegativeLocation();
    }

    public NegativeLocation() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                JPanel panel1 = new JPanel() {
                     @Override
                     public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                         return new Dimension(600, 400);
                     }
                };

                JPanel panel21 = new JPanel() {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(300, 400);
                    }
                };
                panel1.add(panel21);

                JPanel panel22 = new JPanel() {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(300, 400);
                    }
                };
                panel1.add(panel22);

                JPanel panel3 = new JPanel() {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(300, 400);
                    }
                };
                panel21.add(panel3);

                JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
                panel3.add(label);

                frame.getContentPane().add(panel1);
                frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                Point point = label.getLocation();
                Point point2 = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(label.getParent(), point, panel21);
                Point point3 = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(label.getParent(), point, panel22);

                System.out.println(point2);
                System.out.println(point3);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So the output is

```
java.awt.Point[x=134,y=10]
java.awt.Point[x=134,y=-395]
```

UPD: Basically, I need to get location of `label` relative to `panel21`. How can I modify this line to achive it?

```
Point point = label.getLocation();
Point point2 = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(label.getParent(), point, panel21);
```

Comment: It's because you passed the location of the JLabel, but passed the labels parent, so the location information is now invalid

Comment: @MadProgrammer but `getLocation()` gives result relative to parent. So I specify parent as source. What's wrong with my logic?

Comment: But the convert location method expects the location of the child in the child's coordinate space, not the parents

Comment: @MadProgrammer so `Point point2 = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(label, new Point(0,0), panel21);` ?

Comment: That would be more correct, it would convert the point 0x0 from the `label`'s coordinate space to the coordinate space `panel21`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the following example...

[image]

```
public class TestLocation01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLocation01();
    }

    public TestLocation01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JPanel outter = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                outter.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
                JPanel inner = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                inner.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Testing");
                inner.add(label);
                outter.add(inner);

                JLabel below = new JLabel("Below");

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(outter);
                frame.add(below, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.setSize(200, 200);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                System.out.println("lable.location: " + label.getLocation());
                System.out.println("label to inner: " + SwingUtilities.convertPoint(label, new Point(0, 0), inner));
                System.out.println("label to outter: " + SwingUtilities.convertPoint(label, new Point(0, 0), outter));
                System.out.println("label.parent to inner: " + SwingUtilities.convertPoint(label.getParent(), new Point(0, 0), inner));
                System.out.println("label.parent to outter: " + SwingUtilities.convertPoint(label.getParent(), new Point(0, 0), outter));
                System.out.println("label to frame: " + SwingUtilities.convertPoint(label, new Point(0, 0), frame));
                System.out.println("label.getParent to frame: " + SwingUtilities.convertPoint(label.getParent(), new Point(0, 0), frame));
                System.out.println("outter to label: " + SwingUtilities.convertPoint(outter, new Point(0, 0), label));
                System.out.println("label to below: " + SwingUtilities.convertPoint(label, new Point(0, 0), below));
                System.out.println("below to label: " + SwingUtilities.convertPoint(below, new Point(0, 0), label));
            }
        });
    }        
}
```

Which generates (on my system) the following output

```
lable.location: java.awt.Point[x=65,y=62]
label to inner: java.awt.Point[x=65,y=62]
label to outter: java.awt.Point[x=76,y=73]
label.parent to inner: java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0]
label.parent to outter: java.awt.Point[x=11,y=11]
label to frame: java.awt.Point[x=76,y=95]
label.getParent to frame: java.awt.Point[x=11,y=33]
outter to label: java.awt.Point[x=-76,y=-73]
label to below: java.awt.Point[x=76,y=-89]
below to label: java.awt.Point[x=-76,y=89]
```

If I pass the `label` as the source component, I get relative positions based upon the relationship between the `label` and the component whose coordinate space I'm trying to convert to.  If I pass the `label`'s parent, I'm using the parent coordinate space instead, which is bound to produce an incorrect result

If you look at the relationship between `label` and `below` it makes sense to that you would get negative results, as `label` is above and to the right of `below`

Answer (score 7):

For me it's correct behaviour. Imagine following. Main panel contains a child with location x=0 y=100. If you convert the main panel 0,0 point to the child it returns us 0, -100.
In fact it doesn't matter which component is parent of which. The logic is to add (all subtract) all translate() calls which are applied to graphics when parent renders child.

Comment: @Nikolay Kuznetsov did you tried to add different colors as JPanel.setBackground and then to resize of JFrame, now I understand after Stas replied, coordinates are correct, you linked Point to another JPanel (not parent, then there is negative amount :-)

Comment: @mKorbel and Stas, please see my update, I need to get location of label relative to panel21. Is my approach correct?

Comment: I think the approach you mentioned above is correct Point point2 = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(label, new Point(0,0), panel21);